# make barchart with D3 using google form data in real time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar chart with D3 using google form responses, but I cannot make it. I was trying with the google sheet URL, but the code does not show te graph. Is it possible?

This is my code

```
/ Función para cargar los datos y crear la visualización inicial
function loadData() {
  d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KevinSantos93/examen/main/prueba.csv", function (csvData) {
    // Guarda los datos en la variable global
    data = csvData;

    // Crea la escala X
    x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.Country; }))
      .range([0, width])
      .padding(0.2);

    // Crea la escala Y
    y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return +d.Value; })])
      .range([height, 0]);

    // Crea el eje Y
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    // Añade el eje Y
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis") // Agrega una clase para seleccionar el eje Y
      .call(yAxis);

    // Añade el eje X
    svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x-axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


    // Llama a la función de actualización para mostrar inicialmente todos los datos
    updateVisualization("Mundo");
  });
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without more context. Can you check the console in your browser and let us know what error you're seeing? Also, which version of d3 are you using?